# Typform embedded as a widget: can't change size of the form

Tags: angular, embedding, typeform

I embedded Typeform into my angular project, but can't find a way to change it's size.

`home-page.component.ts`

```
import {createPopup, createSlider, createWidget} from "@typeform/embed";


  openTypeform() {
    createWidget("my-typeform-id", { container: document.querySelector("#formId")!});
  }
```

`home-page.component.html`

```
<div class="home-page">
    <p><button (click)="openTypeform()">click to open popup</button></p>

    <div id="formId" style="width: 100%; height: 500px; border: 2px #ccc solid;"></div>
```

The `div` I am embedding also has size defined, but at the end it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: i went to dev tools and there I can chnage the size of the `iframe` then it get's bigger. still can't figure out how to makes it bigger, cause I can't overwrite style of iframe or?

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the CSS too:

```js
import { createPopup, createSlider, createWidget } from "@typeform/embed";
import "@typeform/embed/build/css/popup.css"
import "@typeform/embed/build/css/slider.css"
import "@typeform/embed/build/css/widget.css"
```

Only import CSS files for the embed types you are using in your app.

Alternatively you can also find the latest CSS at `https://embed.typeform.com/next/css/<name>.css`. However if you install the embed SDK locally I'd suggest you use the CSS file from your local installation.